# How to force quotes in every field while saving an excel worksheet as a csv file?

Tags: vb.net, excel, csv

Here is my situation.

```
data = "" & data & ""
xlsheet.Range(crange).Value = data
xlfile.SaveAs(FileName:=finalfilename, FileFormat:=6)
```

This code puts " around the data, puts the data in the range and saves the workbook(xlfile) with one worksheet(xlsheet) as a csv file.

If I open the csv file in notepad I find these following

1.quotes are removed
2.leading 0 from numbers are removed

How to ensure that quotes are present while saving the file programatically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This line is not doing anything:

```
' Append empty strings on front and back (i.e., do nothing). '
data = "" & data & ""
```

Try this:

```
' Append double quotes on front and back. '
data = """" & data & """"
```

Does that help?

---

**UPDATE**: I could be off-base here, but I think the problem may simply be that you don't have enough fine-grained control over **what Excel is doing when it saves a CSV file**. As I recall, by default it does not place quotes around values unless they are needed to qualify a discrete cell that may contain data that would otherwise mess up the CSV format. For example, it puts quotation marks around cells with text values that include commas.

Presumably it also converts single quotes in text values with double quotes in the CSV file and encloses text values containing quotation marks with, well, quotation marks.

The most obvious way of getting around this, to me, would be simply to **save the data to disk yourself**. This way you can manually put quotation marks around every cell and not worry about what voo doo Excel may be performing automatically on the `SaveAs` call.

Obviously, it's annoying because it's more work. But it's the only idea that's coming to my mind at the moment. Anyway, it shouldn't be *that* much work.

Comment: Kind of... now 3 quotes are added in front and back of the data in the csv file.like """mydata""". when i open it in excel there is " in front and back of every cell data. Though it is good, thats not needed, We need quotes in the csv file not while opening in excel

Comment: Yes Dan, Excel sucks really while exporting. I see that it has a robust tweakable import functionality while just a small 'Save As' function for doing the export. MS sucks :(

Comment: Excel doesn't quote every value because its not needed and wastes space. It also considers leading zeros to be formatting information which it doesn't store. The only way to store leading zeros in a CSV format that Excel will understand is to write 01 as "=""01""" (quote equals quote quote zero one quote quote quote). Why are you jumping through Excel in the first place? Its fairly easy to write your own CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a custom format for the cell you need to quote?

If you set a custom format to the cell column, all values will take on that format.

For numbers....like a zip code....it would be this '#' For string text, it would be this '@'

You save the file as csv format, and it will have all the quotes wrapped around the cell data as needed.

Comment: Beware boilerplate copypaste answers, especially on old posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12481173/419 - can appear spammy. Perhaps consider flagging the questions as dupes.

Comment: Considering it was my previous answer to another question that is close to the same, i figured it would be applicable.  Thanks though.